# Getting Error while using Generic Dao in room with java

Tags: java, android, generics, android-room, dao

when I try to use Generic Dao in android Room I get this Erro :

> Cannot use unbound generics in query methods. It must be bound to a type through base Dao class.

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Delete;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RawQuery;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface BaseDaoAccess<T> {
    @Insert
    Long Insert(T entity);

    @Update
    void Update(T entity);
    @Delete
    void Delete(T entity);

    @RawQuery
    LiveData<List<T>> RowQuery(String query);

}
```

Comment: Meaning that your `T` type must be declared at compile time otherwise your DAO won't get generated.

Answer (score 1):

Due to *type erasure*, Java can't tell at runtime what `T` you mean. You can provide this information by creating a subtype that has the `T` *bound* to a specific type, such as this:

```
public interface CarDao extends BaseDaoAccess<Car> { }
```